# SQL LIKE Operator not returning rows

Tags: php, mysql

This is my MySQL statement, I want to search record by status or description.. this statement works fine in phpMyAdmin, but it is not working in php script.. Any Suggestions Please..

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, 
    "SELECT * FROM `statuses` 
    where statuses.`status` LIKE  '%$search%' OR 
    statuses.`description` LIKE  '%$search%'");
```

Comment: Use prepared statements

Comment: Show more code. And @Swellar suggest, learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQLinjection

Comment: MySQL cannot see your PHP code. Please share the actual generated SQL.

Comment: This is the actual Query
{SELECT * FROM `statuses` 
    where statuses.`status` LIKE  '%$search%' OR 
    statuses.`description` LIKE  '%$search%'}

Comment: Then that's the problem. You want to search for a literal dollar-search string, but double-quoted strings in PHP are subject to variable interpolation. I bet you've also disabled PHP error reporting.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález hahahaha too true!

Answer (score 0):

I hope you write everything  correct but there may be error in how you fetching data. Here are the things you need to check.

- check your connection string
- If you are retrieving data then use something like below

  while($row = $result->fetch_array())
   {
       echo $row['example_col_name'];
   }
- You can do one more thing if everything alright store your query to a variable and echo out that one then you will see what query is passing .